# WKWebView showing white screen, with native<->webview communication

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiview, wkwebview

Here are the functions and props inside my ViewController Class,
webViewContainer is a just a View. The page does render because it prints `WEBVIEW MSG WORKING` to console, but it does not appear where the View is, or it does but is just white. Removing the native-webview communication and making a direct reference from a WebView to the variable works as expected, but I need to retain the messaging functionality.

```
@IBOutlet weak var webViewContainer: UIView!
var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    contentController.add(self, name: "callback")

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController
    print(webViewContainer.frame);

    webView = WKWebView(frame: webViewContainer.frame, configuration: config);

    webView.loadHTMLString("<html><body><script>try {webkit.messageHandlers.callback.postMessage('WEBVIEW MSG WORKING');} catch(err) {console.log('Can not reach native code');}</script><h1>WEBVIEW SHOWS</h1></body></html>", baseURL: URL(string: "http://localhost"));
}

func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    guard let response = message.body as? String else { return }
    print(response)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the line

```
self.webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)
```

Adding it to the end of viewDidLoad method should fix your issue.